Telerik Winforms UI Radpropertygrid PropertyValueChanged event
I have a common Propertyvaluechanged event on different Radpropertys
How can I extract the Name of the radpropertygrid
 private static void Rpg_PropertyValueChanged(object sender, PropertyGridItemValueChangedEventArgs e)
 {

I want to now the name of the store or de name op the propertygrid
// prgPersoon
     //ClsPropertystors.Store_to_class(Pstore_pradres, PrAdres);
     //ClsAdressen.Bewaaradresvaneenpersoon(PrAdres);
     //Pstore_pradres["Id"].Value = PrAdres.Id;

     // rpgAdres
     //ClsPropertystors.Store_to_class(Pstore_pradres, PrAdres);
     //ClsAdressen.Bewaaradresvaneenpersoon(PrAdres);

